# Search with linear probing pseudocode

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I came across this pseudocode for finding an element in a hash table using linear probing in my class but no explanation was given on what the variables represent

A is a hash table with N cells and starting point is at cell h(k), want to find element with key k

```
findElement(k)
   i = h(k)
   p = 0
   repeat
      c = A[i]
      if c == null
         return NO_SUCH_KEY
      else if c.key() == k
         return c.element()
      else
         i = (i+1) % N
         p = p+1
   until p == N
   return NO_SUCH_KEY
```

can someone explain what does the line i = (i+1) % N do? is it to increase key value, in that case why is p incremented by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through the code, commenting what we know, shall we?

Importantly, the `%` symbol is the modulus operator. `a % b` returns an integer `c` between `0` and `b-1`, where `c` is the remainder of `a` divided by `b`. For example, 15 divided by 12 is 1, with a remainder 3: `15 % 12 = 3`. Similarly, 16 divided by 4 is 4, with a remainder 0: `16 % 4 = 0`.

```
findElement(k)

   // Assuming h() is a hashing function, i will be the hash of k.
   i = h(k)

   // We're unsure of p's purpose yet, it's probably a loop counter.
   p = 0
   repeat

      // c is the value at position i, which is the hash of k.
      // so c is a candidate for being the element for key k.
      c = A[i]

      // If there's nothing at A[i], then stop.
      if c == null
         return NO_SUCH_KEY

      // If c's key is k, then we've found the right node, return it.
      else if c.key() == k
         return c.element()

      // If there's something at A[i], but it's not for k, then there was a hash collision.
      else

         // Find the next index
         // In this case, we're just looking at the next integer from our starting point,
         // modulus N (the size of the node array).
         i = (i+1) % N

         // Increment the loop counter
         p = p+1

   // If we've been through the whole structure, stop and return NO_SUCH_KEY.
   until p == N
   return NO_SUCH_KEY
```

So this code looks for the key starting from `h(k)` and keeps moving forward, looping at the end of the array back to the start, until it's gone through the entire array. At each step, it's looking for a node with key `k`.

Better names for the variables would have been:

```
k: targetKey
i: candidateIndex
p: numElementsVisited
c: currentNode
A: storage
N: sizeOfStorage
h(): calculateHashValue()
```